# og.follows facebook api returns null

Tags: facebook, api

I am trying to get a list of followers who are my friends or facebook pages I like. Facebook API lists og.follows as the way to access this data but despite giving all permissions in the access token, I get empty data [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQRj2.png)

Comment: What are you expecting to be returned when you make that call? which documentation are you working off?

Comment: @Igy Seems obvious sindhus is referring to this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.follows, attempting a GET to https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.follows. I have the same problem. Follows made, all permissions on token, and an empty response in Graph Explorer. og.likes works for one test profile, doesn't for another.

Comment: And are you posting the follows via the og.follows endpoint? I also have no follows on that edge, but i don't think i've ever posted and og.follows action either, so i think that's expected

Comment: @Igy GET, not POST. And what I and most others expect is that this would list the profiles the FB website shows under "friends|following" (list populated when I check 'friend' and don't uncheck 'follow'). Why would follows posted on og.follows be treated any different? Or, more to the point: do you have any advice on the original issue of there being no data?

Comment: I mean - how are you sure there are og.follows actions present for the user you're checking? Is your app also posting them? I have zero of them on my own profile as far as I can tell - og.follows doesn't show everyone the user follows (that's the `/<user>/subscribedto`edge in version 1 of the Graph API)

Comment: @Igy I admit to only programming for FB, not using it, forgive my ignorance of its history. I guess that the 'follow' on another FB profile used to be called 'subscription', and is still accessed as such; and the og.follows object is for something separate, and not what the OP needs. Is this correct?